# find-file opens file but buries its buffer when ECB is activated

Tags: init-file, buffers, find-file, prog-mode

I have a hook in my `.emacs` file that activates ECB when prog-mode entered:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'ecb-activate)
```

When I open the first file that starts a `prog-mode`, it seems to cause `find-file`* to open the file, but then 'bury' it below all the other buffers. By this I mean that it opens the file, so that I can find it in the list of buffers, but it doesn't switch to that buffer, as I would expect.

If I comment out the line above, it behaves as it should (opens the file and switches to its buffer). Also, once ECB is activated, opening new files behaves as it should.

My question is, how do I stop it from doing that, so that when I open a file, I get that file's buffer? Am I using ECB wrong, i.e. are you not meant to activate it in the mode hooks?

*I am also running `ido-mode`, so maybe it's not actually calling `find-file`,  I get very confused with what's actually going on under the hood.